# PythonのSconsについて

Tags: windows, python2

お世話になります。
Windows10環境のPython2.7にsconsを追加しました。
また、下記ページからMinGW-w64をダウンロードして、32ビット版の環境をインストールしました。
https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/
この状態で、sconsコマンドでビルドを行おうとすると、

```
scons: warning: No version of Visual Studio compiler found - C/C++ compilers most likely not set correctly
File "C:\Python27\Scripts\scons.py", line 201, in <module>
```

というエラーが出てしまいます。
sconsでGCC等を利用することはできないのでしょうか。
また、利用できるのであれば、何か設定が不足しているのでしょうか。
ちなみに、システム環境変数の「PATH」には、「[インストール先フォルダ]\mingw32\bin」を追加しており、「gcc --version」で下記のメッセージが出力されることは確認しています。

```
gcc (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

以上、何かアドバイスを頂けると幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ビルドスクリプトの先頭に`env = Environment(ENV = os.environ)`のようなものは書いてますか？Sconsはデフォルトでは環境変数は読まないらしいので

Comment: すみません。sconsを再インストールしたら解決しました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

お世話になります。
sconsをインストールしなおしたら解決しました。
ご迷惑をおかけして、申し訳ありませんでした。